# Retrieve image path from php after javascript changed src

Tags: javascript, php, image

I completely confused, I had this code

```
<label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
          <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?> id=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]";?>>
```

When I click on an image, it opens an upload dialog box to choose an image to replace the given one. This Javascript code

```
$('#img-frm input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        // Get the input number
        var str = this.id.split("[");
        var i = str[1].substr(0,str[1].length-1);
        var s = 'img-pict[' + i + ']';
        // Get the new picture address
        var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        // Preview the new picture
        document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;
        str = $(this).val().split("\\");
        var n = str.length;
        s = 'img-name[' + i + ']';
        document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = str[n-1];
    });
```

allows me to actually change the image I clicked on with the image I selected in the dialog box. In this code you can see I am changing the `src attribute` of the image tag (the lines below just display the filename under the image). Third, I have this test code

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
```

The problem is that the $_FILES array is completely empty when I click on an image, change it and submit the form. Note that the initial image was the result of a previous posted form. I thought I solved this issue two days ago but it still occurs. I need help! Here are all the codes

**File 1**

```
<?php
...

// Upload pictures
$folder = '../images/tmp';
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name){
    if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1 && (false !== strpos($_FILES['files']['type'][$i],'image'))){
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $folder.'/'.$name)){
            // Redirect to the Upload form
            header('Location: osi_upload.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/preview.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/npm.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui-smoothness/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../js/osi_jquery.js"></script>
<title>OSi, Panafrican Photographer</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<header class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><a href="index.php"><img src="../images/osi_logo_white.png" alt="OSi" class="img-responsive center-block"></a></div>
  <div class="text-uppercase col-xs-12 col-md-8 hide-sm">
    <div class="text-center">african international photographer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 hide-sm"><img src="../images/afrique.png" alt="africa_white" class="img-responsive center-block"></div>
</header>

<section class="container no-pad-left-right">
  <div class="col-xs-12 alert-info pad-top-bottom"><strong><?php echo $osi->clsdate($event_dte).' - '.$eventname_fr.': '; ?></strong><?php echo $post_fr; ?></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 alert-info pad-top-bottom"><strong><?php echo date('M d Y', strtotime($event_dte)).' - '.$eventname_en.': '; ?></strong><?php echo $post_en; ?></div>
  <?php
    $i = -1;
  foreach(glob($folder.'/*') as $filename){
        $file[++$i] = $filename;
    } ?>

    <form action="osi_upload_confirm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="img-frm" method="post"><?php
    // Medium and large devices
    switch($gallery){
        case 1:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 1-->
            <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      for($n=0;$n<=$i;$n++){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
          <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?> id=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]";?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 2-->
            <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[0]" ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[0].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[0]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[0]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[0].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[0]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      for($n=1;$n<=$i;$n++){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 3-->
            <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
            foreach($arr=array(0,4) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[1]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[1].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[1]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[1]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[1].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[1]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      foreach($arr=array(2,3,5,6) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 4-->
      <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      foreach($arr=array(0,1,4,5) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[2]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[2].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[2]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[2]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[2].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[2]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
            foreach($arr=array(3,6) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        { ?>
            <!--Canvas 5-->
            <div class="col-md-9 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
      foreach($arr=array(0,1,2,4,5,6) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[3]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[3].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[3]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[3]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[3].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[3]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div><?php
            break;
        }
        case 6:
            { ?>
            <!--Canvas 6-->
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[0]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[0].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[0]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[0]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[0]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[0].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[0]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
            foreach($arr=array(1,4) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[2]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[2].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[2]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[2]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[2]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[2].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[2]"; ?>>
        </div>
            </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
            foreach($arr=array(3,5) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
        <?php
            } ?>
            </div><?php
                break;
            }
            case 7:
            { ?>
        <!--Canvas 7-->
        <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
        foreach($arr=array(0,4) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
          <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?>>
              <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[1]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[1].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
              <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[1]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[1]); ?></strong></div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[1]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[1].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[1]"; ?>>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
        foreach($arr=array(2,5) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
          <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?>>
              <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[3]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[3].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
              <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[3]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[3]); ?></strong></div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[3]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[3].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[3]"; ?>>
          </div>
        </div><?php
                break;
            }
            case 8:
            { ?>
        <!--Canvas 8-->
        <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
        foreach($arr=array(0,4) as $n){ ?>
                <div class="in-block">
          <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
            <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
        </div>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </div><?php
        foreach($arr=array(1,2,3) as $n){ ?>
          <div class="col-md-3 no-pad-left-right hide-sm">
            <div class="in-block">
              <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
                <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
                <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
              </label>
              <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
              <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
            </div>
          </div><?php
        }
                break;
            }
            case 9:
            { ?>
        <!--Canvas 9-->
        <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad-left-right hide-sm"><?php
        for($n=0;$n<=$i;$n++){ ?>
          <div class="in-block">
            <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
              <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-2">
              <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
            </label>
            <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
            <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
          </div>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </div><?php
                break;
            }
    } ?>

  <!--Extra small and small devices-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad-left-right hide-md"><?php
  for($n=0;$n<=$i;$n++){ ?>
    <div class="in-block">
      <label for=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
        <img id=<?php echo "img-pict[".$n."]"; ?> src=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> class="canvas-1">
        <div class="alert-success pad-top-bottom text-center" id=<?php echo "img-name[".$n."]"; ?>><strong><?php echo basename($file[$n]); ?></strong></div>
      </label>
      <input type="file" id=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?> name=<?php echo "img-input[".$n."]"; ?>>
      <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo "".$file[$n].""; ?> name=<?php echo "img-hidden[".$n."]"; ?>>
    </div>
    <?php
  } ?>
  </div>

  <!--Updating form-->
  <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-bottom"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <label>Name of the new portfolio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="eventname_en" value=<?php echo "'".$eventname_en."'"; ?> required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <label>Nom du nouvel album</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="eventname_fr" value=<?php echo "'".$eventname_fr."'"; ?> required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <label>Artist name/Nom de l'artiste</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="artist" value=<?php echo "'".$artist."'"; ?> required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <label>Write the presentation text</label>
    <textarea cols="53" rows="10" name="post_en" class="form-control form-except input-sm" required><?php echo $post_en; ?></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <label>Entrer le texte de présentation</label>
    <textarea cols="53" rows="10" name="post_fr" class="form-control form-except input-sm" required><?php echo $post_fr ?></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <label>Select the gallery type/Selectionner le type de galérie</label>
      <select name="gallery" class="form-control input-sm" required><?php
            $n = $i + 1;
            switch($n){
                case 4:
                { ?>
          <option value="0" <?php if($gallery==0) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery intro</option>
          <option value="1" <?php if($gallery==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 01</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if($gallery==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 02</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if($gallery==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 03</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if($gallery==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 04</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if($gallery==5) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 05</option>
          <option value="6" <?php if($gallery==6) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 06</option>
          <option value="7" <?php if($gallery==7) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 07</option>
          <option value="8" <?php if($gallery==8) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 08</option>
          <option value="9" <?php if($gallery==9) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 09</option><?php
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                { ?>
          <option value="1" <?php if($gallery==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 01</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if($gallery==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 02</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if($gallery==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 03</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if($gallery==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 04</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if($gallery==5) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 05</option>
          <option value="6" <?php if($gallery==6) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 06</option>
          <option value="7" <?php if($gallery==7) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 07</option>
          <option value="8" <?php if($gallery==8) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 08</option><?php
                    break;
                }
                case 6:
                { ?>
          <option value="1" <?php if($gallery==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 01</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if($gallery==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 02</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if($gallery==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 03</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if($gallery==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 04</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if($gallery==5) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 05</option>
          <option value="6" <?php if($gallery==6) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 06</option>
          <option value="7" <?php if($gallery==7) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 07</option><?php
                    break;
                }
                case 7:
                { ?>
          <option value="1" <?php if($gallery==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 01</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if($gallery==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 02</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if($gallery==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 03</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if($gallery==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 04</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if($gallery==5) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 05</option><?php
                    break;
                }
                case 8:
                { ?>
          <option value="1" <?php if($gallery==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>Gallery type 01</option><?php
                    break;
                }
            } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <label>Name of the City/Nom de la ville</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="city" value=<?php echo "'".$city."'"; ?> required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <label>Date de l'évènement/Event date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="event_dte" value=<?php echo "'".$event_dte."'"; ?> required>
    <input type="hidden" name="photoid" value=<?php echo "'".$photoid."'"; ?>>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right"><a href="osi_upload.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button></div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

**File 2**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){       
    // Change clicked pictures
    if(!$('#img-frm input[type="file"]')){
        return;
    }
    $('#img-frm input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        // Get the input number
        var str = this.id.split("[");
        var i = str[1].substr(0,str[1].length-1);
        var s = 'img-pict[' + i + ']';
        // Get the new picture address
        var new_img = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        // Preview the new picture
        document.getElementById(s).src = new_img;
        str = $(this).val().split("\\");
        var n = str.length;
        s = 'img-name[' + i + ']';
        document.getElementById(s).innerHTML = str[n-1];
    });
});
```

**File 3**

```
<?php
// Test $_FILES array
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

I can't see where I messed up, the `src attribute` of the image change with Javascript but the form post an empty `$_FILES array`.

Comment: Can anybody help, please? I am stuck. I can't post the image I changed.

Comment: I made some tests and realized that if I change (using Javascript) the hidden input near the img tag, I don't get data from the `$_POST` variable. But if I made the same change with for instance one of the text input below the form, I get the data from the `$_POST` variable. I was wondering if it is possible that the submit button doesn't process the part above the form (all pictures are above) but only the part below the form, despite the fact that everything is between the same `<form></form>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

After making some tests, I realized that the issue comes from the HTML form that doesn't send the `$_FILES` data.

First, the `<!---Extra small and small devices--->` code overwrites the `//Medium and large device` data because they had the same variables names, I made the variables names distinct.

Second, There are too many successive `divs`. It seems to cause a breach in the form, I not sure to understand why? But I had no data with those successive `divs` (or maybe I didn't saw the actual issue there). But I changed the layout of my `divs` and now my form works perfectly.

So, two issues: the `php` variables names and the `divs` layouts.